# Create a shortcode for native WooCommerce search form

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, search

How can I create a shortcode for the native WooCommerce search form, so that it can be used elsewhere? In the secondary menu, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to functions.php. You can then use the shortcode [search_form], or whatever you choose to name it, in a menu. I used it in the navigation label field of a custom link.

```
function search_form_shortcode() {
    return get_product_search_form(false);
}
add_shortcode('search_form', 'search_form_shortcode');
```